# Query regarding the failure of frisby test cases results

Tags: testing, automated-tests

While running the code with necessary validations, the test cases are not executed. It throws the following error message.

1) *Frisby Test*: Test case for single post

Message:

```
 Expected 500 to equal 201.
```

Stacktrace:

```
 Error: Expected 500 to equal 201.
at null.<anonymous> (/home/admin/wrkspc/api-tests/node_modules/frisby/lib/frisby.js:462:42)
at null.<anonymous> (/home/admin/wrkspc/api-tests/node_modules/frisby/lib/frisby.js:1043:43)
at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

2) *Frisby Test*: Test case for single post

Message:

```
Error: Error parsing JSON string: Unexpected '<'
Given: <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.53 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.53</h3></body></html>
```

Stacktrace:

```
Error: Error parsing JSON string: Unexpected '<'
Given: <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.53 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.53</h3></body></html>
at _jsonParse (/home/admin/wrkspc/api-tests/node_modules/frisby/lib/frisby.js:1174:11)
at Frisby.<anonymous> (/home/admin/wrkspc/api-tests/node_modules/frisby/lib/frisby.js:919:20)
at null.<anonymous> (/home/admin/wrkspc/api-tests/node_modules/frisby/lib/frisby.js:1081:18)
at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Expected 500 to equal 201.
```

Means that what you are testing is throwing an error.

```
Error parsing JSON string: Unexpected '<'
```

Just means that the response you received was not in proper JSON format. In this case, it seems to be html. This second error is expected your system under test is throwing an error message in the format it is comfortable with, html, and not in JSON.

The real error:

```
The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `inspectBody()` to you see return of the test.

More informations: http://frisbyjs.com/docs/api/#inspectBody()